# Adding an Animator in Unity3D immediately kills FPS

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have the following problem:

I have a scene, with only 3 objects: a Camera, a Light, and a 3D model (imported from 3dsmax). No code at all, everything works as expected (it shows the model).
I then enable the Animator, and add an Empty Animator Controller to it. Immediately, the FPS goes to something ridiculously low (1.8 FPS). I emphases this: no animations are enabled in the Controller!

(Actually, my application is much bigger, but this is a minimal case which reproduces the problem: In my main application, I do a lot of things with this model: rotate, zoom, move, click to select a specific part of it, etc. We tried to add animations (included in the original FBX file). But adding an animator to the object immediately kills the FPS, without any animation)

Anyone have ideas how to do this? Thanks!

Comment: is it reproducible on another machine?

Comment: Did you test it on a mobile device? If so, what are the specifications of your device?